# Smoke detector triggers without any fire, smoke and carbon monoxide

Tags: smoke-detectors

Does anyone know why a bunch of networked #smokeDetectors would go off when there’s no #smoke, fire, or #carbonMonoxide?

My house is pretty humid. Could that be a factor?
I’ve tried vacuuming the detectors based on the theory that it might be dust inside the detector. That doesn’t seem to have done much.

Please let me know if you have a clue because this is super annoying

Comment: Some detectors do have a problem with high humidity setting them off.

Comment: Humidity and some  may sound when the detection material has aged and is depleted.

Comment: Are you charging a lead-acid battery in the vicinity of a carbon monoxide detector? Hydrogen emitted by an overcharged battery (or one undergoing equalization) will set it off.

Comment: They are all mine 4 years old at the most. Humidity got up to 70%. So maybe that’s it. We engaged the a/c and will wait for another event

Comment: It depends on what sort of tech the detectors use.  Are you able to post a brand and model number. Or a photo of a sticker ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Spiders are a common issue for smoke detectors.

Comment: If they’re interconnected, it only takes one unit to ruin your day. And these things do fail. The hardest part is finding out which one.

Comment: Mine kept going off when there were wildfires affecting air quality and we lost power to the house for a few days due to a thunderstorm.